# How to get exit code in zabbbix using system.run

Tags: bash, shell, zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I'm facing a little simple problem that is get the exit code of a script using Zabbix system.run.

```bash
zabbix_get -s hostname -k system.run["hostname"]
```

How can I get an exit code of this command?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be in `$?`, did you check that?

Comment: You don't... system.run[] returns only stdout and stderr. You also only use system.run[] for tests. You need to create a script that prints $?, and put it in UserParameters.